# Spectral theory; separation of spectrum, eigenprojections

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, generalized-eigenvector

I have been reading Kato's perturbation theory book and on spectral theory in general, and I have a question regarding the separation of spectrum (c.f. Kato, Perturbation theory for linear operators, Theorem III.6.18). I'll explain the general setup below.

$X$ is a complex Banach space and $\mathcal{L}:X\to X$ is a bounded operator. For $z\in\sigma(\mathcal{L})$ which is isolated, he defines the spectral projection as $\pi_z=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_C (wI-\mathcal{L})^{-1}dw\in B(X)$, where $C$ is a small circle around $z$, and $B(X)$ is the space of bounded operators on $X$.

When $\mathcal{L}$ is finite rank, he mentions that $\pi_z$ is the projection onto the generalized eigenspace associated to $z$.

Does this naturally extend to operators which are not finite rank; for example if $z$ is an isolated eigenvalue such that $\pi_z$ has finite dimensional range, then can we say $\pi_z$ projects onto the generalised eigenspace of $z$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can find that in the book of Dunford and Schwarz ("Linear Operators, Part I"). The assumption on the finite-dimensional range of the projection is crucial here and cannot be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is an isolated point of the spectrum, then $\pi_z$ is well-defined by the integral around $z$ that encloses no other points of the spectrum. And,
$$
          (\mathcal{L}-zI)\pi_z = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(\mathcal{L}-zI)(wI-\mathcal{L})^{-1}dw \\
  = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(w-z)(wI-\mathcal{L})^{-1}dw
$$
The same is true for all positive powers of $\mathcal{L}-zI$, i.e., $(\mathcal{L}-zI)^n$ is turned into $(w-z)^{n}$ inside the integral for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$:
$$
         (\mathcal{L}-zI)^n\pi_z =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(w-z)^{n}(wI-\mathcal{L})^{-1}dw.
$$
These give the negative coefficients in the Laurent series expansion of the resolvent around $z$. And $(\mathcal{L}-zI)$ implements a ladder from one coefficient to the next. $(\mathcal{L}-zI)^n\pi_z$ is eventually found to be $0$ by making assumptions about rank.